# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении?

Tags: грамматика, пунктуация

Предложение:

> К примеру, в первой таблице, при значении коэффициента, равному 0.7, параметр составляет 180, а во второй таблице, при значении коэффициента, равному 0.8, параметр составляет 185.

Comment: Эти 0.7 и 0.8 из категории нумерации и отбивки круглых чисел, и то не в нашей системе, правильно — 0,7 и 0,8 подобно десятичной дроби.

Answer (score 1):

Во избежание **избытка** знаков препинания в предложении можно  убрать запятые перед ПРИ ЗНАЧЕНИИ. Но Ваш вариант постановки знаков **допустим**, так как обстоятельство ПРИ ЗНАЧЕНИИ КОЭФФИЦИЕНТА выражено существительным с предлогом.

А вот **грамматические ошибки** нужно исправить. Возможен такой вариант предложения:

***К примеру, в первой таблице при значении коэффициента, равном 0.7, параметр составляет 180, а во второй таблице при значении коэффициента, равном 0.8, параметр составляет 185.***

***При значении КАКОМ? - равнОМ***